# Identify/Extract identical curves from a multicurve plot plot

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have a plot containing 300 curves. Is there any method in Matlab 2014a so I can identify which curves are identical to each other? To be more specific, if I have 10 curves on a single figure, curve 1 is identical and very close to curve 2, same happens with curve 3,4 and 5. Is there any automated on way for Matlab to do that instead of visual inspection?

Thanks

George

Comment: What type of information do you have about the curves? How do you generate them?

Comment: I have the temperature on a 24 hour basis for each day. I would like to identify the temperatures of the days that are identical and very close to each other so I can represent them with their average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might take a while but if your 300 curves are in an array say `c(n,300)`. `n` is arbitrary and is the number of point you have one each curve.

For `i in 1:300` and `j in i:300` you want to compare `c(:,i) - c(:,j)` to a given threshold (which depends on how much you want two curve to differ from each other).
I do this with: `abs(sum(c(:,i) - c(:,j))) < thresh` -> sum the difference for all points between the 2 curves, the difference should be small if the curves are similar.

When you find a `c(:,j)` below the threshold you want to remove it from the pool of 300 curve.
This is done by `c = c(:,~ismember(1:size(c,2),j));`
Which give you a code like:

```
i = 1;
thresh = 1; %arbitrary threshold here adapt to you needs
while i<size(c,2)
j = i+1;
while j<size(c,2)
if abs(sum(c(:,i) - c(:,j))) < thresh
c = c(:,~ismember(1:size(c,2),j)); %remove the curve j from c
else
j = j+1;
end
end
i = i+1;
end
```

**EDIT**
When you do the comparison to the threshold you actually want to compare to the absolute value of the sum.
Changed my code to reflect that.

Comment: @user3775255 Can you accept the answer if it answers your question?

Comment: I tried your code with 12 curves but the simulation takes very long time to complete. Actually I couldn't wait and I had to exit Matlab. Is this normal?

Comment: @George Strange, can you post you data somewhere? On a matrix `c` I arbitrary created  it runs very fast.

Comment: How can I post my data? Matrix c is a 24x12 matrix.

Comment: I would also like to know which columns have been removed and store them in a different matrix. Instead of removing the curves I would like to store them in a different matrix so I can see which columns of matrix c are identical or close to each other. How this can be done?

Comment: I tried the code again and it's working fine now. But, can I store the identical curves in a different matrix? Thanks

Comment: Does the code check if say curve 1 is similar to curve 7? Or just if curve 1 is similar to curve 2, curve 2 to curve 3, curve 3 to curve 4 and so on.

Comment: I think the code only checks if curve 1 is similar to curve 2, curve 2 similar to curve 3 and so on. It does not check if curve 1 is similar to curve 3. Thank you very much for your help. If you could help me with this last bit it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @George, yes it does. It takes curve 1 and looks if it is similar to curve 2, 3, ... until the end. If it finds a similar curve it removes it from c.
Then it takes cure 2 (if it has not been removed) and looks again for similarities with curve 3, 4 , ... to the end.
And so on until you reach the end of the matrix.
I will update my post to answer your other questions.